# Angular: scope.$apply() is breaking my app?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn Angular. I'm making a to do list. I want to be able to remove chores from my list. I believe I'm removing them correctly from my array of chore objects. However, I read around and it seems like I have to use `scope.$apply();` in order for the $scope to update and take it out of the list in the view when I remove something. However, angular throws an unreadable trace when I add that line:

Here's the github account with bower_components and node_modules ignored: https://github.com/EdmundMai/angular_todolist

Here's the function in my controller:

```
toDoListApp.controller("ChoresController", function($scope) {
    $scope.chores = [{
        name: "laundry",
        hours: 3
    },
    {
        name: "dishes",
        hours: 0.5
    }
    ];
    $scope.submit = function() {
        if ($scope.chore.name) {
            $scope.chores.push({name: $scope.chore.name, hours: 2});
            $scope.chore.name = '';
        } else {
            alert("none");
        }
    };
    $scope.removeChore = function(unwanted_chore) {
        var index = $scope.chores.indexOf(unwanted_chore);
        alert($scope.chores.length);
        $scope.chores.splice(index, 1);
        alert($scope.chores.length);
        $scope.$apply();
    };
});
```

And my view partial:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" name="chore_name" ng-model="chore.name">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<div ng-repeat="chore in chores | filter:chore.name" ng-controller="ChoresController">
    {{ chore.name }} - {{ chore.hours }} <a href="#blah" ng-click="removeChore(chore)">X</a>
</div>
```

=== **UPDATE** ===

Looks weird when I try to "x" the laundry item, the dishes remain in $scope.chores, but when I click "x" on dishes (which should empty out the array in theory), it says the laundry item still remains in chores... Am I deleting the item incorrectly????

Comment: I don't think you need an apply. The apply function is only used to trigger a digest and update the angular code when data is changed outside the angular scope. Your changes are with in the scope so angular should handle it correctly.

Comment: But my view doesn't change at all even though I delete the element (as you can see from the length of the chores array).

Comment: does any of your angular code work on the page, without the removeChore function? Is your bindings working?

Comment: Here is a fiddle of your scenario, and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/9amE6/

Comment: it also works in the fiddle by @aet without the apply. I think if you are getting an error from this it will be a Angular $digest is already in progress error, which would break angular.

Comment: Edmund, can you share more of the code with us please?

Comment: in the fiddle posted by @aet, the console shows $apply already in progress https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply. removing the $apply call and the view does update.  If your view is not updating (with or without $apply), something else on the page is interfering.

Comment: @AndrewCounts I updated the question to include my controller

Comment: @aet I updated the question. Which file do you need

Comment: Well, at this point, I almost want to see ALL of it :) Something very strange is going on, what you are trying to do is a basic angular operation.

Comment: @aet Give me a second I'll put it up on github!

Comment: @aet https://github.com/EdmundMai/angular_todolist with the bower_components and node_modules ignored

Comment: Well, I see one thing, you are including the ChoresController twice. It is set as the controller for the route, and is also set inside the partial. Try removing the ng-controller from the ng-repeat div.

Comment: I removed it but it still doesn't update

Comment: Would you be willing to switch to an angular 1.2 build?

Comment: sure how would I do that?

Comment: Change your index.html to point at the different version: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: no luck... whyyyyyyyyy

Comment: I think it's resetting the $scope.chores variable or not completely deleting? When I look into the console log it doesn't look like the item is deleted even though I used splice

Comment: @aet I figured it out..... it was the href="#blah". could you explain why it broke it???

Comment: Hmm, maybe the #blah was causing a page reload. At least thats my guess.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated in the comments, you should be able to accomplish this without using `$apply` however you are using it incorrectly. It takes a function that when finished will update the view. Try something like:

```
$scope.removeChore = function(unwanted_chore) {
    $scope.apply(function () {
        var index = $scope.chores.indexOf(unwanted_chore);
        alert($scope.chores.length); // prints 2
        $scope.chores.splice(index, 1);
        alert($scope.chores.length); // prints 1
    });
};
```

Comment: also if you only need to call the apply to update the view then it can be called safely like this if(!$scope.$$phase){$scope.$apply()};

Comment: Something else is going on, there is not a good reason why $apply should have to be called for a view update in this case.

Comment: @aet Agreed, this should work, perhaps OP is mixing controllers and the scope is getting broken?

Comment: Why does it work in the fiddle but not in my code? I updated the question to show my controller

Comment: @Edmund Are you using multiple controllers, possibly nesting them in your view(s)?

Comment: @Fiver hey fiver I pushed all my code onto github (besides bower components and node modules) https://github.com/EdmundMai/angular_todolist

Answer (score 0):

First off, the  `| filter:chore.name` in the ng-repeat does not make sense, you are using the input element in the form to add a new chore but using it as a filter in the ng-repeat. That should explain the flickering. This probably is throwing your indexes off if you search and then delete a chore. Check this plunk out - it has all of your code minus the filter.
http://plnkr.co/edit/64VxMQeq9zKZhfEcPHpd?p=preview

You should not need an `$apply` in this case. The `$apply` is used to run non-angular stuff in the digest.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the link then `#blah` is added to the current location. That in turn causes the routing service to react.

It wants to change to the route `blah` and since there is no such route defined it takes the `otherwise` route. That means that the the view is reloaded (rather refreshed) and voila, everything is like it was before.